# how to get day month and year from wp_post_object?

Tags: posts

i am trying get day month and year of a post from WP post object.

what i did is:

```
       <?php
        $cpost=get_post($_GET['p_id']);
        echo $cpost->post_date;echo "<br>";
      ?>
```

Outputs:

```
    2013-12-26 13:25:18
```

what i need is, day month and year as:

```
   26 Dec 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
echo get_the_time('j M Y', $_GET['p_id']);
```

References:

- [`get_the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)